# I cannot use SDL2 on centOS , maybe I install it failed. error:No available video device

Tags: x11, sdl-2

My system is centOS 6.5 . I download the  SDL version 2.0.4 from official site. Then I configure,make,make install depend on SDL Wiki step by step. 
there is a config list :

---

```
SDL2 Configure Summary:
Building Shared Libraries
Building Static Libraries
Enabled modules : atomic audio video render events joystick haptic      power filesystem threads timers file loadso cpuinfo assembly
Assembly Math   : mmx 3dnow sse sse2
Audio drivers   : disk dummy oss
Video drivers   : dummy
Input drivers   : linuxev linuxkd
Using libudev   : YES
Using dbus      : NO
Using ibus      : NO
```

I am a newbie , so maybe there will something wrong just like the Video drivers : dummy ?
I don't know, and I continue the installation ,make and make install.
Then I try to compile && run a the first program by downloading lazy foo's tutorial  first program named Hello_SDL. by use this command

```
g++ 01_hello_SDL.cpp -w  -o 01_hello_SDL  `sdl2-config --cflags --libs`
```

compile succeed ! but when I run the binary,it report error:
   SDL could not initialize! **SDL_Error: No available video device**
It's too bad. I google this error and try these methods:

1. export SDL_VIDEODRIVER=X11
2. DISPLAY=:0 ; export DISPLAY
3. shutdown the GUI : vi /etc/inittab change to id:3:initdefault:

The above of methods are unused. I am driven to madness and my first SDL program still cannot run. who can help me ? Do I need to re-install X11 and how to install it on centOS ?

Comment: `Video drivers   : dummy` is a big clue.  Running `configure` on my Debian box with the prerequisite `-dev` packages installed nets me `Video drivers   : dummy x11(dynamic) opengl opengl_es2 wayland(dynamic)` as well as a new `X11 libraries   : xcursor xdbe xinerama xinput2 xinput2_multitouch xrandr xscrnsaver xshape xvidmode` line.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Make sure you have the appropriate development libraries installed before running `configure`.

On Debian & derivatives you can do that via `apt-get build-dep libsdl2`.  I'm not sure what the analogous procedure is on CentOS, cursory Googling suggests `yum-builddep SDL2` as a possibility.

Comment: The problem is solved : use this to install dependencies: sudo yum install rpm-build alsa-lib-devel libX11-devel libXScrnSaver-devel libXau-devel libXcursor-devel libXext-devel libXfixes-devel libXi-devel libXinerama-devel libXrandr-devel libXrender-devel libXxf86vm-devel mesa-libGL-devel pulseaudio-libs-devel

Answer (score 0):

You need to install X11 development packages.

I develop my SDL2 game on CentOS 5.10 and it works, but you should know that there is no out-of-the-box joystick/gamepad support on CentOS 5/6 in SDL2.

```
su
yum groupinstall "X Software Development"
```

or see on stackoverflow:

[Development packages for X11 for CentOS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2556807/development-packages-for-x11-for-centos)